# docker-compose up with cassandra container does not return

Tags: docker, cassandra

I have a simple docker-compose file

```
 version: '3'
services:
  cassandra:
    image: "cassandra:3.11.4"
    container_name: leguan_cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    volumes:
      - ./build/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
```

which does never return. Can you please give me an example how the docker-compose returns after ensuring the cassandra to be ready and usable?

Thanks in advance
Markus

Comment: I am trying to understand what "return" means to you but if you're referring that you're able to keep the prompt try adding `-d` or `--detach` to the `docker-compose up` command e.g. `docker-compose -d up`

Comment: Also note that Docker Compose doesn’t take responsibility for checking that any service is “ready and usable”.  If you use `docker-compose up -d` or have other services in the same `docker-compose.yml`, Compose will move on immediately; if the database takes a while to start up, Compose won’t wait for it.

Comment: I am currently trying to use docker-compose to start a cassandra before unit tests and want to stop it afterwards. So I am using the gradle plugin "com.avast.gradle:gradle-docker-compose-plugin:0.8.14", which calls the docker-compose without -d. So did I understand it right? I have to start it with -d and wait for the database coming by myself?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you for your answers,

with this docker-compose.yml it works for me now:

```
version: '3'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: "cassandra:3.11.4"
    container_name: leguan_cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    volumes:
      - ./build/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ $$(nodetool statusgossip) = running ]"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 50
```